# Hosting a Django CMS project at the root of a domain, and a second one at a path under the root

Tags: apache2, mod-wsgi, django-cms

I used the same method for hosting multiple django cms sites under one domain for example 'example.com' .example.com is my my main project and example.com/blog is my sub project. Both are independent projects.But when I login to example.com/blog its URL will be automatically redirecting to example.com. I used to set both the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL and SESSION_COOKIE but no use.Any one please help me.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess project3 python-home=/home/nidhinjames/project3/virtualenv2.7 python-path=/home/nidhinjames/project3/project3
WSGIScriptAlias /blog /home/nidhinjames/project3/project3/project3/wsgi.py process-group=project3 application-group=%{GLOBAL}
Alias /blog/static /home/nidhinjames/project3/project3/static

WSGIDaemonProcess school python-home=/home/nidhinjames/djangocms/myvenv python-path=/home/nidhinjames/djangocms/school-module
WSGIScriptAlias /school /home/nidhinjames/djangocms/school-module/school_module/wsgi.py process-group=school application-group=%{GLOBAL}
Alias /school/static /home/nidhinjames/djangocms/school-module/districts/static

WSGIDaemonProcess project python-home=/home/nidhinjames/project1/virtualenv2.7 python-path=/home/nidhinjames/project1/project1
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/nidhinjames/project1/project1/project1/wsgi.py process-group=project application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

Comment: Do you set ``SESSION_COOKIE_PATH`` differently for each? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_PATH

Comment: my project is in 'info' directory and i used to make SESSION_COOKIE_PATH='/info' and LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/info' but when i login to example.com/info i will automatically redirecting to example.com url.This is my issue.